# NUnit 3 using Visual Studio 2015 How do I supply my tests with some parameters?

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, nunit

For example, I might write lots of Selenium tests for my staging website, now instead of writing the exact same code again but with the URL on my live website I'd like to reuse the code.

(I might need more than just the URL, I might need a different login/password etc.)

I thought it might be possible by using a .testsettings file and in my tests I could read what the current URL is that I should test against etc.

There has to be a way, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing your test configuration in a simple text based file. It could be as simple as URI on the first line, username on the second and password on the third, etc. Or, if you already have NewtonSoft.JSON in your project, create a simple JSON config file.

Then in your Test Assembly Setup, you could read in that file and parse it into a global static test settings object that you can access from all of your tests.

I would check the default `TestSettings.json` into source control so it is always available, then you can check if a `TestSettings.local.json` is present. If so, load it, otherwise load the default.

You could also set the defaults in code and override them if `TestSettings.json` is present.

To load the file before all of your tests run, use the [SetupFixture](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute) attribute which allows you to run code when your test assembly loads, before all of your tests run.

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [SetUpFixture]
  public class MySetUpClass
  {
    public static TestSettings Settings { get; set; }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
      // Load your settings file here into the static
      // Settings property
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Eventually, we'll add a feature so you will be able to supply parameters through the runsettings file or via command-line parameters to the console runner. However, Rob's recommendation has the advantage that it will work no matter how you run your tests.

Comment: Yes but :) I see one problem. Rob cunningly suggests that I could read that file and parse it into a global static test settings object that I can then access from all of my tests.....    how would I do that? since as far as I can tell, I can't know which test runs first, how would I get that test that runs first to read the file and parse it into a global object? I think I'd have to have each test read the file.

Comment: I will update my comment with code. NUnit has an assembly setup that runs before all of your tests.